# How to open shading menu or select material preview?

Tags: interface, navigation

Here is the [video](https://youtu.be/62puxI7zT-Q?t=424), I can't open shading menu, how to open it?

Is there other way to select material preview?

Comment: it should be Z but I don't know how she gets additional options like X-Ray in this pie-menu (it's Alt Z to switch to X-Ray mode)

Comment: That layout is pretty well standard in 2.93 and 3.0 but she's using 2.83 by the look of it and even with the 3D Viewport pie menu addon, you still don't get the X-Ray option in that version.